# How to display WP_Mail errors?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How do I make PHP display the exact error after else statement, rather than echoing a text?

This is the code Im using and I want to know exactly what is going wrong after sending the mail:

```
function deliver_mail() {

// if the submit button is clicked, send the email
if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

    // sanitize form values
    $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
    $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
    $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

    // get the blog administrator's email address
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

    // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>You have sent the mail!</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'error occurred';
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the error message?

Answer (score 14):

have a look at this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_failed/

Debugging wp_mail() can be a lot easier with this simple method.
It will display a more helpful error message (the original phpmailer error) than Wordpress will by default.
Just add this function to display the real wp_mail() error.
But only use this for debugging.

```
   // show wp_mail() errors
    add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', 'onMailError', 10, 1 );
    function onMailError( $wp_error ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($wp_error);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Comment: Why cant it be used in production? Id like to know if sth went wrong

Comment: The author probably meant that using `print_r($wp_error)`  you can display sensitive data. There's nothing wrong to use this hook to show user friendly notification like "Something went wrong. Try again".